# Get array collection of an object from firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

i'm trying to fetch Products collection from specific user, and the request isn't working.
here is my code:

the first request function:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>> get productsUser {
    return usersCollection.doc(uid).collection("Products").snapshots();
  }
```

and here where I try to present the Products array I fetch (or didn't...):

```
class _ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GivitUser givitUser = Provider.of<GivitUser>(context);
    final DatabaseService db = DatabaseService(uid: givitUser.uid);
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.productsUser,
        builder: (context, snapshotProduct) {
          if (snapshotProduct.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshotProduct.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Loading();
          }

          return Container(
            color: Colors.blue[100],
            height: 400.0,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: snapshotProduct.data.docs.map(
                  (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    var snapshotdata = document.data() as Map;
                    Product product =
                        Product.productFromDocument(snapshotdata, document.id);
                    print(product.name);
                    return Container(
                      child: Text(product.name),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
          );
```

Thanks to everyone who will help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), and store the result of the fetch as state, or you can use a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to manage the state for you, and automatically rebuild the widget tree each time a new snapshot is received. In either case, the following two guides may also be helpful:

- [Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)
- [Async/Await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Here's an example of how you might use StreamBuilder in your case:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.blue[100],
    height: 400.0,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object>>(
        stream: usersCollection.doc(uid).collection("Products").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) => Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: asyncSnapshot.data.data.docs.map(
            (DocumentSnapshot document) {
              var snapshotdata = document.data() as Map;
              Product product =
                  Product.productFromDocument(snapshotdata, document.id);
              print(product.name);
              return Container(
                child: Text(product.name),
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I used already StreamBuilder as you suggested, now I edited the code so you can see the full version. maybe another idea or now you can spot a potential problem?